# Listing div's if dropdown value = x, what might be the problem?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm listing businesses, and I want to filter them by brand. I have a function to do it, but unfortunately i don't know why doesn't it work. It makes the list elements disappear, and reapper if 'ALL' is chosen, but not showing anything if something specific is chosen from the dropdown.

```
 <select name="dropdownbrand" id="dropdownbrand" class="dropdowncontent">
    <option value="ALL">ALL</option>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  </select>
```

I'm getting the data from database

```
 <p class="brand">Brand:<?php echo $data['brand']??''; ?></p>
```

The function:

```
 $('#dropdownbrand').on('change', function(){
        var brand = $(this).val();

        if (brand == 'ALL') {
            $('.business').show();
        } else {
            $('.business').hide(); // hide all
            $('.business .brand').filter(':contains('+brand+')').closest('.business').show(); // show only matched records
        } 
    });
```

Comment: `:contains()` is case-sensitive. Does the contents contain `volvo` or `Volvo`?

Comment: It would probably be better to put the brand in the `class` and filter using that. `<p class="brand <?php echo strtolower($data['brand']) ?>">`

Comment: @Barmar That was the problem! It was value='mercedes' not value='Mercedes' as in the div. Thank you!